# AOC monitor glitches and gets stuck on some screenshot of a previous session

Tags: multiple-monitors

Sorry for the title, I'm having trouble putting it into words.
What seems to happen is I run a game and the monitor freezes, shows my desktop with a few programmes I had running before and I can't interact with it until I end the games programme.
I thought it might be a driver issue, but they are all up to date and it only seems to happen with certain games.
Some specs
AMD FX6300
NVIdia GeForce FTX 1060
AOC e2270Swhn monitor

Comment: What specific games? What mode are you running them in (window, fullscreen, borderless window)?

Comment: Mostly paradox games, but I just tried Medieval Total War 2 in borderless window mode and it caused the glitch, so  I have a hunch it's because of windowed mode.